# Use VIM to pass options to PDF reader

Tags: bash, vim, pdf, vimrc

I have a BASH script that recompiles a latex document and reopens it up using my PDF reader when the buffer is written back. The command in my '.vimrc' looks like this:

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.tex !~/scripts/latex_update.sh %
```

This works well, but the reader always opens the PDF to the first page. This is inconvenient since I have to scroll to look at the changes I just made. I would like to set a VIM variable called 'page_num' and pass it as a second argument to my script.

I have tried this in VIM:

```
:let g:page_num=2
```

I then changed my 'autocmd' to:

```
 autocmd BufWritePost *.tex !~/scripts/latex_update.sh % g:page_num
```

However, the global 'page_num' variable does not get replaced with its value. How can I get VIM to pass the value of 'page_num'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `:exe` to expand the variable before executing the rest of the command should work:

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.txt exe '!~/scripts/latex_update.sh %' g:page_num
```

Note that you don't need to concatenate (the `.` operator) or put a space before `g:page_num` since `:exe` does that as part of its argument expansion.

Comment: You should use `shellescape(expand('%'))` instead just `%` just in case the file has spaces or some other weird character.